# Adding php.exe to my system variables

Tags: php, cmd, windows-8, cakephp-2.0

I use Windows 8,I have added php.exe to system path I can run it from cmd but php.exe comes out in different window.My question is how do I make php.exe open in my cmd window.
I am runing cakephp console shell, I can' t read the error message because php.exe comes and leaves immediately.I am a newbie to programming and I sincerely need help.

Answer (score 0):

`MY Computer`  <kbd>></kbd>  `System properties` ( Button on Top Navigation Bar )  <kbd>></kbd>   `Advanced system settings`  <kbd>></kbd>  `Environment Variables`  <kbd>></kbd>  ( In Side Environment Variables Window Select ) `The path in the user variables section & click the Edit Button.`
 <kbd>></kbd>   ( Now After Click On Edit ) `at the End Paste Your Php Path,Where Php actually Install`

`Example:`  **C:\wamp\bin\php\php.** OR **C:\xampp\php\php.exe**

<kbd>></kbd>  Now, Press `Ok`

[image]